# How to add visitor count in magento admin page?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add visitors count in magento admin page. Please anyone help me how to do?

Comment: Do you mean the visitor count that is at customer -> online customers?

Answer (score 1):

To do it custom (and put it on the dashboard) you would need to extend the admin dashboard. Specifically, I think you want to [add a new tab to the dashboard](https://www.openstream.ch/developer-blog/adding-a-new-tab-to-magento-admin-dashboard/).

Alternatively, you could just [install an extension for Google Analytics](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-analytics-dashboard-reports.html). Honestly, this is probably the route I would go. Google does a great job tracking all this stuff already. If you want something more robust later on, there are paid extensions that do more.